# Do I need collect my baggage between connecting flights within Germany, on a single ticket?

Tags: usa, transit, luggage, germany

I am flying to Charlotte from Chennai via Frankfurt *and* Munich in Lufthansa. The whole ticket is booked as one trip.

On traveling from Chennai, I have a layover at Frankfurt first and then one at Munich before I board the flight to Charlotte from Munich. Do I need to collect my baggage and check-in again during the layover in Frankfurt before I board the flight to Munich?

*Note:* This journey required a Schengen visa and I have got the same. So, I might have to go through the immigration while I'm at Frankfurt

Comment: You need a type C Schengen visa (and *not* an “airport transit visa”) for this flight. You will indeed enter the Schengen area in Frankfurt and leave it in Munich, going through a passport check in both airports but you shouldn't have to collect your luggage.

Comment: Thank you @Relaxed. Yes, I have not taken the airport transit visa. I have taken the C Schengen Visa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's booked as one trip with the same airline, then the lugggage will be checked through to the final destination with a *very* high likelihood. To be absolutely certain, ask the Lufthansa employee at the counter when you check in in Chennai.

Answer (score -1):

I made a trip through Munich Airport from USA to Israel. My checked luggage was transferred for me all the way to Israel, and all the way back from Israel to my return destination. I had 2 hours to walk through Munich from landing gate to the next gate in the same terminal. It was a bit rough for me because of mobility issues. We had to walk through a controlled part of the airport, then through a border/passport check before entering a waiting area for the flight from Munich to Israel and also to return. You will already have passed basic airport security/German customs in Frankfurt and be inside the airport security lines in Munich. The customs/passport/Visa checkpoint I passed through was only for those who were leaving the country again.

- Munich Airport Connecting info:
  https://www.munich-airport.com/connecting-flights-260553
- Frankfurt Airport connecting info:
  https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights-and-transfer/transferring-at-fra.html